# String formatting with commas in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, formatting

Let's I have parts of user's address that should be formatted in single string.
Address components are

```
Street  
City  
Phone  
State  
Zip
```

and should be formatted to string `street city, phone, state zip`. (2 commas).
Problem is that every field can be `null`. So if `street == null` and `city == null`, then I should have string `phone, state zip` (1 comma). Problem is in controlling number of spaces and number of commas
**How can I avoid and minimize the number of null-inspections?**
My current code is

```
  var formatAddress = function(address) {
     var retVal = ""

     if (address.street || address.city)
     {
        retVal += address.street ? address.street + " " : "" 
        retVal += address.city ? address.city : "" 
        retVal += ", ";
     }
     retVal += address.phone ? address.phone + ", " : ""

     retVal += address.state ? address.state : ""
     retVal += address.zip ? " " + address.zip : ""  

     return retVal
  }
```

Comment: may be better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @jbabey I am finding another way to do this. I don't ask to refactor my code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var fields = [[address.street, address.city], [address.phone], [address.state, address.zip]];
return fields.map(function(part) {
    return part.filter(Boolean).join(" ");
}).filter(function(str) { return str.length; }).join(", ");
```

Or, in a loop and without `filter` and `map`, but mapping property names to their values:

```
var fields = [["street", "city"], ["phone"], ["state", "zip"]];
for (var strs=[], i=0; i<fields.length; i++) {
    for (var parts=[], j=0; j<fields[i].length; j++)
        if (address[fields[i][j]])
            parts.push(address[fields[i][j]]);
    if (parts.length)
        strs.push(parts.join(" "));
}
return strs.join(", ");
```

Answer (score 1):

add it to an array and remove some adjacent comma's and spaces.

```
var street = "street";
var city = "city";
var phone = "phone";
var state = "state";
var zip = "zip";
[
    street,
    city, ",",
    phone, ",",
    state,
    zip
].join(" ") //add all items with spaces in between
.replace(/(\s*,\s*)+/g, ", ") //remove multiple spaces before or after commas
.replace(/\s+/g, " "); //remove any other double spaces
```

Answer (score 0):

Could be cleaner with a function:

```
function formatAddressPart(part,concatString){
     return part ? part+concatString : "";
}


var formatAddress = function(address) {
     var retVal = ""

     if (address.street || address.city)
     {
        retVal += formatAddressPart(address.street, " ");
        retVal += formatAddressPart(address.city,""); 
        retVal += ", ";
     }
     retVal += formatAddressPart(address.phone,", ");

     retVal += formatAddressPart(address.state," ");
     retVal += formatAddressPart(address.zip,"");  

     return retVal
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your strings in an array, then use the join method and remove multipel consecutive commas with a single one

```
a = [address.Street, 
     address.City, 
     address.Phone, 
     address.State, 
     address.Zip].join (', ').replace (/(, ){2,}/g, ', ');
```